# Winston : understanding logging levels

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

Reading and fiddling with Winston, I'm puzzled as to why the logging levels are ordered as they are and why the transports behave in the way they do (well, at least the Console one). I'd appreciate if someone could, perhaps even thoroughly, with real use case examples, explain why logging with Winston works this way?

For example, I setup my logger like this :

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  levels: winston.config.syslog.levels,
  colors: winston.config.syslog.colors,
  level: "debug",  // I'm not sure what this option even does here???
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
      colorize: true,
      handleExceptions: true,
      json: false,
      level: "debug"
    })
  ]
});
```

So, if I do `logger.debug("Test");`, then it will log `debug: Test`, fine. But if I do `logger.info("Test");`, then nothing happens.

The problem I have is that, If I want to log to the console *eveverything* **but** `debug` messages, what do I do? ... or even `debug` *and* `info` messages, but log everything else?

Coming from a Java world, using the standard loggers, I am used to having `debug` being more "fine grained" than `warn` and the loggers worked backwards; setting the logging level to `info`, for example, did log everything but `debug` (or something).

Also, what if I'd like a logger to log only `error`, `warning` and `info` messages, how would I do that with Winston?

#### * EDIT *

Apparently, this order of level is unique to `winston.config.syslog.levels`. So the only question remaining is : "Is it possible to, somehow, restrict a transport to a very specific logging level only?"

Comment: indeed there was a bug in winston pre 2.0  : `winston.config.syslog.levels` had its levels' numeric values in reverse order than default values ! Using them makes winston unusable. This has been fixed in 2.0.0 : https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v200--2015-10-29

Comment: Since this question has received a lot of views: in winston 3.0 it is possible to use a custom formatter to restrict transports to log only specific level[s]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56918394/4451284

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/flatiron/winston#using-custom-logging-levels), you can set your own Logging levels, 0 being lowest, and associate colours with it. Now, if you don't want to log the lowest level, just set the `level` property to the corresponding level. By default, the console logger has it's level set to `info`

So, here is an example:

```
logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  levels: {
    'info': 0,
    'ok': 1,
    'error': 2
  }
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.ConsoleTransport)(silent: options.silent, level: 'ok')
  ]
});
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of reversing the order of the levels. However, this is not answering why the official levels are the way they are and all. ALso, it does not answer the question about having a transport (i.e. Console) intercepting only certain levels. In your example, the transport would echo any `ok` and `error`, and not just `ok`.

Comment: Intuitively, I presume that you'd want to echo above a given level. I do not know if there is functionality in winston to filter only specific logs, but as a work-around, you can juggle your levels so that `OK` has higher priority than `ERROR`, that way you can filter it out... I'll look around to see if winston can filter the logs for a single level.

Comment: Yes, I think that is what is happening. You can't set specific levels to be shown while ignoring higher levels. See [Issue #89](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/issues/89)

Comment: Thanks, even though that issue was over 2 years ago, it made me realize that the root of the problem was the `syslog` levels/colors, as the default levels do not have this issue. I edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Ha Ha... Didn't think 2 years later I would reading this and would find your answer.

Comment: @pyros2097 I barely even remember writing it! :D

Answer (score 3):

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
       levels: {
        'info': 0,
        'ok': 1,
        'error': 2
       },
    colors: {
        'info': 'red',
        'ok': 'green',
        'error': 'yellow'
       },
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({level:'info',colorize: true})
    ]
});
logger.log('info',"This is info level");
logger.info("This is info level");
```