# Winston / Morgan logging avoiding duplicate entries

Tags: node.js, winston, morgan

I just implemented Winston Logging and it works as expected but i came accross a few issues which i cant find answer for.

The way winston works as far as i can tell, the set log level and anything below as far as priority gets used, like on error it will also include info logs etc. Is there a way to create a specific log level lets call it HTTP or db where i only log http or db events to and they don't end up in the combined file or console ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A better solution is to use a single logger with a format function as a "level filter" to specify which transport logs which specific level.  Here is the solution (note, `levelFilter` could easily be extended to take an array of acceptable levels).

The key insight is that if no `info` object is returned from the formatter chain, nothing gets logged.

```js
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');

const levelFilter = (level) =>
  format((info, opts) => {
     if (info.level != level) { return false; }
      return info;
  })();

const logger = createLogger({
  transports: [
    new transports.Console({
        format: format.combine(
          levelFilter("info"),
          format.json()
        )
    }),
    new transports.File({
        filename: "test.log",
        format: format.combine(
          levelFilter("error"),
          format.json()
        )
    }),
  ]
});

// ONLY is logged to test.log
logger.log({
  level: 'error',
  message: 'abcd'
});

// ONLY is logged to console
logger.log({
  level: 'info',
  message: '1234'
});
```

Comment: Yeah but @ MisterniceGuy also want to use separate log files for specific purposes, thats why multiple loggers, but maybe there is a way how to dynamically change a filename property

Comment: In my example I had a console transport and a file transport, but you could just as easily use two file transports, one that logs the error-level messages and one that logs the info-level messages.  Still works with a single logger, though.

Comment: Core developer also suggest this solution. More: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1108

Answer (score 0):

I can init a winston with a parameter, in your case filename. I use similar setup for logging separated cron tasks (I use `type` parameter instead `filename`, which is used as a prefix in log, so I can identify problems in multiple cron tasks in one log file). I hope you are familiar with ES6 syntax.

utils/winston.js

```
const { createLogger, transports } = require('winston');

const infoLogger = filename => createLogger({
    transports: [
        new transports.File({
            filename: 'info-' + filename,
            level: 'info'
        }),
        new transports.Console(),
    ],
        exitOnError: false
    });

const errorLogger = filename => createLogger({
    transports: [
        new transports.File({
            filename: 'error-' + filename,
            level: 'error'
        }),
        new transports.Console(),
    ],
        exitOnError: false
    });

export default filename => ({
    errorLogger: errorLogger(filename).error,
    infoLogger: infoLogger(filename).info
});
```

So in a your code you can import custom winston setup from utils and initialize it with a filename. Be careful, I basically export only error function from winston `errorLogger(filename).error`, You can modify it in way acceptable for you

main.js

```
import logger from './utils/winston';
const { errorLogger, infoLogger } = logger('http.log');
errorLogger('some http fail'); // destination file => error-http.log
infoLogger('some http info'); // destination file => info-http.log
```

Comment: That's what i have currently but if i say error it will also log anything below error to that file which includes info etc. I am trying to create a file which does not log anything besides for example my db query's

Comment: @MisterniceGuy I think we dont understand each other, I made some changes to make it more clear

Comment: yes the new code makes your approach more clear, ultimately you create 2 different instances of the logger. This might work but not sure it is the best approach

Comment: @MisterniceGuy yes its a bit weird approach, maybe you can try another logger package, because as I see it, winston's way of error logging is kind of tech standard so it is probably optimal way. If you find something interesting let me know