# Winston log level filter

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I am trying to use multiple transports. I also want to be able to log only one or more specific level(s) on a transport, where Winston logs from the given level and all which are more sever, so that I cannot by default be as selective as I would like to be.

I currently have 3 transports. One logs everything to console, one logs everything to file, and the third I want to log only levels HTTP_SEND and HTTP_RECV to a different file.

It is the third that I am having problems with. When I breakpoint the function `levelFilter`, I never see `info.level != 'info'`.

What am I doing wrongly? NB my code is based heavily on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56907439/winston-morgan-logging-avoiding-duplicate-entries).

```
const winston = require('winston');

// Custom logging levels. We use all of those from https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5424, although we change the values.
// We also add some custom levels of our own, which are commented with "".
const logLevels = {
    none: 0,                    // no error logging - don't log with this, set it in process.env.LOG_LEVEL to turn off logging
                                // Could also be achieved by silent=true in winston.createLogger, from process.env, but this is simplest
    emergency : 1,              // system is unusable
    alert: 2,                   // action must be taken immediately
    critical: 3,                // critical conditions
    unhandledException: 4,      // unhandled exception
    error: 5,                   // error conditions
    coding_bug: 6,              // hard bug. E.g switch stemante hits default, etc
    warning: 7,                 // warning conditions
    notice: 8,                  // normal but significant condition
    info: 9,                    // informational messages
    debug: 10,                  // debug-level messages
    HTTP_SEND: 11,              // HTTP request sent
    HTTP_RECV: 12,              // HTTP request sent
    called: 13,                 // function called
    returns: 14,                // function returns
    log_everything: 15,         // always the lowest level, so that we can log everything
  };

  const options = {
    everythingToDailyLogFile: {
      level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'log_everything',
      filename: `./logs/everything.log`,
      handleExceptions: true,
      json: true,
      maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
      maxFiles: 5,
      colorize: false,
    },
    httpActivityToLogFile: {
      level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'log_everything',
      filename: `./logs/http_activity.log`,
      handleExceptions: true,
      json: true,
      maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
      maxFiles: 5,
      colorize: false,
    },
    everythingToConsole: {
      level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'log_everything',
      handleExceptions: true,
      json: false,
      colorize: true,
    },
  };  

  const myFormat = winston.format.printf( ({ level, message, timestamp , ...metadata}) => {
    let formattedMessage = `${timestamp} [${level}] : ${message} `  
    if(metadata) {
    formattedMessage += JSON.stringify(metadata)
    }
    return formattedMessage
  });  

  const levelFilter = (levelToFilterOn) =>
  winston.format((info, _options) => {
      // If no info object is returned from the formatter chain, nothing gets logged
      if (toString.call(info.level) === "[object Array]")
      {
        if (info.level.includes(levelToFilterOn)) { return info; }
        return false;
      }
      
      if (info.level != levelToFilterOn) { return false; }
        return info;
})(); 

module.exports = winston.createLogger({
  levels: logLevels,
  transports: [
      new winston.transports.Console({
          format: winston.format.combine(
            levelFilter(process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'log_everything'),
            winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS' }), 
            myFormat
          )
      }),
      new winston.transports.File({
        filename: "./logs/bet_squad.log",
        format: winston.format.combine(
          levelFilter(process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'log_everything'),
          winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS' }), 
          myFormat
      )
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: "./logs/http_activity.log",
      format: winston.format.combine(
        levelFilter(process.env.LOG_LEVEL || ['HTTP_SEND', 'HTTP_RECV']),
        winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS' }), 
        myFormat
      )
    }),
  ]
});
```

Comment: Mawg - pings to people who have not interacted with a question do not notify them. (Seven copy-pasta notes about Winston flagged as "no longer needed").

Comment: Thank you I was not aware of that. It was slightly naughty of me anyway, but I was desperate and this was my second bounty offer.  You can be sure that I will not do so again.

Comment: No worries. It it is considered OK to ping one helpful person under, say, one of their answers elsewhere, with a link to a question they would likely be able to help with. However, I tend to advise against overdoing it to one helper, and it is excellent if comments of this kind can be self-deleted when they are no longer needed (it keeps Stack Overflow tidy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and managed to make the third transport work. Your question is unclear, what do you mean by:

> I never see info.level != 'info'.

In any case, if you want the third transport to work you have to configure a environment variable that matches the info level you define in your code

If you want your information level to be `info`, you must define an environment variable because of how you defined the parameter you pass to your `levelFilter` function.
`levelFilter(process.env.LOG_LEVEL || ['HTTP_SEND', 'HTTP_RECV']),`
In order to use that process.env.LOG_LEVEL, you need to use the [dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) that allows you to load env variable from a `.env` file.
Go Ahead and install that package:

```sh
npm install dotenv
```

Create a `.env` file at the root of your project and fill it with this code:

```sh
LOG_LEVEL=info
```

Add this line after your `winston` import as such:

```js
const winston = require('winston');
const dotenv= require('dotenv').config();
```

Thanks to the `dotenv` package, the env variable you defined in the `.env` file is populated in the `process.env` object.
Now if you try `logger.log('info', 'test message %s', 'my string');` you should be able to see the log appearing as well as the `http_activity.log` file populated.

Comment: Thanks for that. Actually, the `env` stuff was just copied from an example. I had thought that it might come on useful in future, but will probably just remove it to make life simpler :-)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica That was the only thing blocking the third transport for me. Could you give a more details snippet of a working example so that I can help you debug?

Comment: Sorry, but I have been really busy these last few days. I have awarded you the bounty. I will try w/o the `env` and let you know how it goes.